# Table of Raw Data to Adjacency Matrix/Sociomatrix

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have a data table arranged like so:

```
ID       Category 1       Category 2     Category 3
Name 1   Example 1        Example 2      Example 3
Name 2   Example 1        Example 2      Example 4
Name 3   Example 5        Example 6      Example 4
....    ....             ....            .....
```

I'm trying to turn it into a table like this:

```
        Name 1     Name 2     Name 3   ....
 Name 1    0        2          0    
 Name 2    2        0          1
 Name 3    0        1          0
  ....
```

Where each cell in the output table represents how many of the categories were the same when compared between IDs. This could also be how many of the categories were different, either one will work. I've looked into adjacency matrices and sociomatrices on stack overflow, as well as some of the matrix matching recommendations, but I don't think that my data table is set up properly. Does anyone have any recommendations on how this should be done?

EDIT: Ah, apologies. I'm using R as my program. Left that bit out

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting your data into a long format first, at which point it becomes a pretty straightforward exercise:

```r
# your data
tdf <- data.frame(ID = paste0("Name ", 1:3), cat1 = paste0("Example ", c(1,1,5)),
                  cat2 = paste0("Example ", c(2,2,6)),
                  cat3= paste0("Example ", c(3,4,4)))
tdf
#>       ID      cat1      cat2      cat3
#> 1 Name 1 Example 1 Example 2 Example 3
#> 2 Name 2 Example 1 Example 2 Example 4
#> 3 Name 3 Example 5 Example 6 Example 4

# the categories are extraneous, what matters is the relationship of ID to 
# the Example values, so we melt the df to long format using the 
# melt function from the package reshape2
lfd <- reshape2::melt(tdf, id.vars = "ID")
#> Warning: attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will
#> be dropped

# create an affiliation matrix
adj1 <- as.matrix(table(lfd$ID, lfd$value))
adj1
#>         
#>          Example 1 Example 2 Example 3 Example 4 Example 5 Example 6
#>   Name 1         1         1         1         0         0         0
#>   Name 2         1         1         0         1         0         0
#>   Name 3         0         0         0         1         1         1

# Adjacency matrix is simply the product
id_id_adj_mat <- adj1 %*% t(adj1)
# Set the diagonal to zero (currently diagonal displays degree of each node)
diag(id_id_adj_mat) <- 0
id_id_adj_mat
#>         
#>          Name 1 Name 2 Name 3
#>   Name 1      0      2      0
#>   Name 2      2      0      1
#>   Name 3      0      1      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is perfect, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user164819 Great! Glad it helped. If you feel I answered your question you should check the green 'accept' box to the left of my answer, and if you liked the answer you can upvote it.